# Error when I try to create a module in jmvtools using RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Using:
RStudio 1.2.5033
R 4.0.4
Jamovi 1.6.16

I'm trying to create a module in jmvtools using RStudio. When I run the command `jmvtools::create('pkg_name')`, I receive this output:

````
jamovi 1.6.16 found at C:\Program Files\jamovi 1.6.16.0\bin\jamovi.exe

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:124:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:375:7)
    at C:\Users\Marcelo Correia\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\jmvtools\node_modules\jamovi-compiler\index.js:277:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Marcelo Correia\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\jmvtools\node_modules\jamovi-compiler\index.js:518:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined ```
````

Comment: If you change "\" by "/" might be works

Comment: I changed using this command:

options(jamovi_home='C:/Program Files/jamovi 1.6.16.0/bin')

But the error persists